# Rxjs - Is there any operator on flatten arguments?

Tags: rxjs

```
map(([[org, additionalFields, key], offset]) => ({org, key, offset, additionalFields})),
```

Is there any operator on flatten arguments?

I want to pass to the next switchMap an object with these arguments

```
{
    org: org, 
    key: key, 
    offset: offset, 
    additionalFields: additionalFields
}
```

Comment: What is wrong with the current de-structuring `([[org, additionalFields, key], offset])`? Is it not working as expected?

Comment: No, but you can write one that flattens to something like [org, additionalFields, key, offset]. You would somehow need to know the property names of the values to create an object. It looks to me that your existing map operator is a good solution.

Comment: Nothing is wrong with this. It works as expected. I want only to "beautify" this line of code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Array.flat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat):

```
map((args: any[]) => args.flat()),
```

This is available in ES2019, which you can specify in `tsconfig.json`:

```
    "lib": [
      "es2019",
      "dom"
    ]
```

Comment: how about the names of properties? Because I want an object.